# What is the name the creature that is X/X where X is the number of sorcery and Instant cards in your graveyard?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I saw a creature in standard who's power and toughness are equal to  the number of sorcery and instant cards in your graveyard.

Does anyone know the name of this card?

Comment: unless I am imagining it and it's really Runechanter's Pike?

Comment: Any more details other than its a creature? do you its color or mana cost? are you sure it is in standard? http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?page=1&action=advanced&text=|[instant]|[sorcery]+[graveyard]

Comment: No sorry, I was played along with Notion Thief and Reforge the Soul. It was standard. I

Comment: http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?text=+[power]+[toughness]+[number]+[cards]+[graveyard] There is no creature currently in Gatherer that matches your description.

Comment: Your card sounds like a mixture of Magnivore and Cognivore. Are you sure you're not mixing them up?

Comment: Definitely Runechanter's pike.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such card (creature or otherwise) that matches your description.

[MTG gatherer search for sorcery + instant + graveyard](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?page=1&action=advanced&text=%7C%5Binstant%5D%7C%5Bsorcery%5D%20%5Bgraveyard%5D)

The closest I could find was the same one you posted in a comment.

[Runechanter's Pike](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=244681)

Comment: Thanks that must have been it . Just wanted confirmation.